# JQuery Chosen prevent automatic vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I recently discovered a functionality of jQuery Chosen which automatically scrolls the .chosen-results Container downwards when you hover the bottom of the container.

[image: Problem]

I already found the function (*result_do_highlight*) which does that: [here](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/blob/master/coffee/chosen.jquery.coffee#L209-L226)

This is the part where the automatic scroll happens in the function:

```
if high_bottom >= visible_bottom
    @search_results.scrollTop if (high_bottom - maxHeight) > 0 then (high_bottom - maxHeight) else 0
else if high_top < visible_top
    @search_results.scrollTop high_top
```

Is there a way to prevent scrolling?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

I forked the Chosen-git and added a workaround: [github.com/puresamari/chosen](https://github.com/puresamari/chosen)

here is how to use it:

## Changes from my side

I added the funtionallity to disable the automatic scroll towards the highlighted option:
Use it like this:

```
$('your_select').chosen({
  scroll_to_highlighted: false
});
```

the parameter ´scroll_to_highlighted´ is optional and default true

Comment: Do you mean vertical scroll?

Comment: You are right, I meant vertical scroll :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forked the Chosen-git and added a workaround: [github.com/puresamari/chosen](http://github.com/puresamari/chosen)

here is how to use it:

## Changes from my side

I added the funtionallity to disable the automatic scroll towards the highlighted option:
Use it like this:

```
$('your_select').chosen({
  scroll_to_highlighted: false
});
```

the parameter ´scroll_to_highlighted´ is optional and default true